# Why do input boxes appear in a different place to a message box VBA EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a worksheet that uses both input boxes and message boxes using vba.

However the input box is displayed way above center of the screen, unlike the message box.

See images below.

Why is this, and can I change the position of the input box ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: *can I change the position of the input box ?* Yes, [InputBox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/inputbox-function) allows you to specify its position (`xpos` and `ypos` parameters).

Comment: Man, it's years since I had to pass in x,y co-ords for a modal dialog.

Comment: @Akina thanks, i see input box can be determined by X and y positions, why are these options not available with a message box ?

Comment: *why are these options not available with a message box ?* It is system, not VBA, object, I think... but you may find its window by caption and then change its position.

Comment: This article describes one method of specifying the location of the message box http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/define-a-position-of-messagebox.shtml